# Get List of Directories and Timestamp in a specific format in HP-UX

Tags: ls, timestamps, hp-ux

I am on HP-UX B.11.11 OS. My **requirement** is to display a list of directories only and the last modified time format should be **DD-MON-YYYY HH:MI:SS AM/PM**. I am able to get the list using either

```
    ls -lF | grep /
```

OR

```
    ls -ld -- */
```

but I am unable to set the time format as I want. The *--full-time* or *--time-style* parameter doesn't work in HP-UX, and HP-UX doesn't have *stat* as well.

**Questions:**

1. **Primary Requirement:** Could anyone please provide me a script to display the list of all the directory names (not files) under current directory and the last modified timestamp in the format mentioned above? I don't need the owner name, group name, size, permissions etc.
2. Is there any other way to display this information without using C or Perl, by just using standard commands and parameters?
3. I was wondering how is WinSCP able to display the full date/time format in the UI ? Anyone knows what command it uses internally to
   display the directory contents in the UI?

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

**UPDATE (edits below only):**
So, Stéphane Chazelas's answer with perl script worked perfectly. Now, I am trying to convert it into a shell script, but I am getting errors while executing it. I have saved the shell script *`dir_list.sh`* under *`/dev/scripts/`*. Could you please help where I am going wrong?

```
#!/usr/bin/sh
# dir_list.sh : Generate a comma separated directory list with last modified timestamp
# Navigate to the directory where listing is required
cd /dev/product/jobs
# Execute Perl script
/usr/bin/perl -MPOSIX -MFcntl -MFile::stat -le '
  setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
  for (<*>) {
    $s = lstat $_ or die "$_: $!\n";
    print "$_," . uc(strftime("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p", localtime $s->mtime))
      if S_ISDIR($s->mode)
  }'
exit 0
```

**ERROR MESSAGE**
Please note that I tried *`#!/usr/bin/sh`* as well, but it failed with same error message: *`interpreter "/usr/bin/sh" not found`*

```
$ ./dir_list.sh
interpreter "/bin/sh" not found
file link resolves to "/usr/bin/sh"
ksh: ./dir_list.sh:  not found
```

## Final Update : RESOLVED - Solution Below

I created a Unix shell script `dir_list.sh` which when called ( `$ ./dir_list.sh` ) searches within the target folder specified in the script and displays the folder names along with its associated timestamp as a comma-separated records

```
#! /usr/bin/ksh
# dir_list.sh : Generate a comma separated directory list with last modified timestamp
#
# Navigate to the Target Directory
cd /dev/product/jobs || exit
#
# Execute Perl script to format the output
/usr/bin/perl -MPOSIX -MFcntl -MFile::stat -le '
  setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
  for (<*>) {
    $s = lstat $_ or die "$_: $!\n";
    print "$_," . uc(strftime("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p", localtime $s->mtime))
      if S_ISDIR($s->mode)
  }'
#
exit 0
```

Thanks to **Stéphane Chazelas** for all your help! 
:)

Comment: **Another Update:** I was able to use `sh dir_list.sh` but it doesn't provide the output in the target directory (says directory path `^M:  not found.`). It shows the output only from the directory from where I am executing the script, in this case /dev/scripts. Is there a way to specify output only in the target directory mentioned in shell script?

Comment: Answers belong in answers, not in questions.  This WWW site does not do things the "RESOLVED" way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unless GNU utilities are installed, your best bet is probably `perl` on those traditional systems:

```
perl -MPOSIX -MFcntl -MFile::stat -le '
  setlocale(LC_TIME, "C");
  for (<*>) {
    $s = lstat $_ or die "$_: $!\n";
    print "$_ " . uc(strftime("%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p", localtime $s->mtime))
      if S_ISDIR($s->mode)
  }'
```

That's `perl`'s interface to the standard POSIX `lstat()` system call that retrieves file metadata and `strftime()` function to format dates.

See `perldoc POSIX`, `perldoc -f lstat`, `perldoc -f stat`, `man lstat`, `man strftime` for details. We use the C locale for `LC_TIME` so we get English month names and `PM`/`AM` regardless of the preferences of the user.

If `zsh` is installed:

```
zsh -c 'zmodload zsh/stat
        LC_ALL=C stat -nA times -LF "%d-%b-%Y %I:%M:%S %p" +mtime -- *(/) &&
          for f t ($times) printf "%s\n" "$f: ${(U)t}"'
```

Above, we're using `perl`'s `uc()` and `zsh`'s `${(U)var}` to convert the timestamps to uppercase. On GNU systems, you could have used `%^b` for a all-uppercase month abbreviation, but it doesn't look like it's available on HP/UX.

Comment: Thanks so much Stephane.. Exactly what I wanted and worked at the first go! :)
If you don't mind, could you please explain or send me a link which provides more info on each of those functions and parameters used? I am new to Unix and Perl.

Comment: I edited the script to make the output comma-separated. Could you please tell me how can I get the month in all caps, I tried with %B, but it shows the full month name instead of capitalizing it. 
Also, how can I convert it into a Shell script (dir_list.sh) to show the all the folders within the directory   /dev/product/jobs/

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention that the Perl script worked for me, and not the second one. I guess zsh is not installed.

Comment: @NICKz, see edit

Comment: Thanks Stephane, that worked! I am now trying to create a shell script but running into issues. I edited my question to include an Update, since I wasn't able to post the whole thing as a comment.

Comment: @NiCkz, most likely you edits the script on a Microsoft system and forgot to convert the line endings to Unix format. On Unix-like systems the line delimiter is LF only while it's the 2 characters CR and LF on Microsoft OSes. So Windows files appear to have trailing CR characters on Unix.

Comment: That's true, I am on Windows 7. I usually use WinSCP and then open the shell script in Notepad++, since I am not very comfortable with Unix command line or the vi editor. Is that why directory path `^M: not found.` error shows up? But, other than that the shell script I posted looks fine?

Comment: @NiCKz, it's OK except you forgot to check for success of `cd`. Change to `cd /dir || exit`. Also here you might as well do everything in perl. Change the shebang to `#! /usr/bin/perl`, and do the `cd` with `chdir "/dir" || die "cd: $!\n";` followed by the rest of the `perl` code.

Comment: You are Amazing! I changed `#!/usr/bin/sh` to `#! /usr/bin/ksh` and also changed `cd /dev/product/jobs` to `cd /dev/product/jobs || exit` and it's working fine. Thanks so much for all your help, really appreciate it :) I'll post the final update to the question so that others can find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

*find . -type d -exec stat {} \;* is the usual Unix System V way. It seems that *stat* becomes *fstat* on HP-UX, so the command becomes
*find . -type d -exec fstat {} \;*

Depending of your requirements, you may have to pipe the output in awk (or nawk or gawk) to get exactly what you expect.

Ref: http://hpux.connect.org.uk/hppd/hpux/Shells/fstat-1.0/man.html

Comment: Thanks. I guess stat is not available as a standard install in HP-UX, but I could be wrong. I was executing the above, and it didn't give me any errors but it started scanning within subdirectories which I don't want. Maybe, there is a way to specify only a particular directory and also not to search within subdirectories.

Comment: if there is an "iostat" command (specialized for IOs), maybe "stat" has a longer name (fstat ? something else ?) but I can't imagine a Unix without a "stat" command — even Mac OSX which is BSD has a "stat" !!!

Comment: can you try (for bin & sbin): find / -type d -name bin -exec ls {}/*stat* \; 2>/dev/null  (or something close if it doesn't work). I long to know the answer :-)

Comment: Will be back tomorrow only, sorry :-)

Comment: I tried the above but didn't work for me, it started navigated through all the directories. The solution provided by @Stéphane worked for me. Appreciate your help :)

Comment: I spent a part of my Sunday to read all the HP-UX manuals downloaded the day before, without finding any **stat** line command for regular files — I was very surprised. Sorry for the poor help :-(