# Move the oldest files into a directory, source directory has more than 10,000 files constantly incoming

Tags: shell-script, ls, ksh, mv, hp-ux

I am working on a command to move the x number of oldest files(FIFO) into a directory, is it better idea to pipe the `"find"` result into `"ls"` or just use the "`ls`" .. please suggest.

```
ls -ltr `/bin/find ${in}/* -prune -name "*.txt"  -type f` | head -10 |     
 while read -r infile ; do                    
     -move the file 
done
```

or should i just use `ls.` 
the reason i am using `find` is: i read some online content that `ls` should be avoided in scripting. but in my code at the end i have to pipe the find results into the `ls`. 
i am worried if `find` result is too big would it might cause any problem.

Comment: I noticed you tagged ksh and hp-ux; is zsh an option?

Comment: No, our OS is hp-ux and we have ksh scripts in that i had to  implement this part.

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449771/117549 may be useful

Comment: 10k files per ...? If it's 10k files per second I suspect we're going to have problems! Mind you apparently a directory can hold 4 billion files.

Comment: If any of the answers solved your problem, please [accept it](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) by clicking the checkmark next to it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

While [perl](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/449771/117549) is probably going to be faster than looping through a large directory "x" times, here's a brute force simple solution.

The outer loop determines how many files will be moved -- 3 in this example. Inside that loop, we initialize an "oldest" file to the first filename that results from globbing `*`. The inner loop then compares every file's timestamp to see if it is older than (`-ot`) the currently-oldest file. If it is, we update the "oldest" filename. At the end of the inner loop, we report and move that file.

```
for((count=0; count < 3; count++))
do
  set -- *
  oldest=$1
  for f in ./*
  do
    if [ "$f" -ot "$oldest" ]
    then
      oldest=$f
    fi
  done
  echo mv -- "$oldest" ./.archive
  mv -- "$oldest" ./.archive
done
```

Comment: Thank you, But in your solution you are looping to every file in that directory how could this improve the performance compared to just  `ls command` , i could just use ls -ltr | head -x then for each file will do the move operation.

Answer (score 0):

## Python `heapq.nsmallest`

bash:

```
find -printf '%T@ %p\n' |
python noldest.py 1000 |
xargs -Ixxx mv xxx directory_for_old_files
```

Here `find` command lists files in format "seconds from 1970 (%T@), space, filename (%p)". Trailing `xargs` command takes filenames from stdin one by one and applies `mv xxx directory_for_old_files` command substituting xxx with them.

noldest.py implementation could be:

```
import sys
from heapq import nsmallest
from datetime import datetime


n = int(sys.argv[1])
date_file_pairs = (line.split(' ', maxsplit=1) for line in sys.stdin)  # generators are lazy

def parse_date(date_and_filename):
    seconds_from_1970 = float(date_and_filename[0])
    return datetime.fromtimestamp(int(seconds_from_1970))

for _, filename in nsmallest(n, date_file_pairs, key=parse_date):
    print(filename.rstrip('\n'))  # lines in sys.stdin have trailing newlines
```

The perfomance depends on implementation of `nsmallest` algorithm from python standard library.